# DDB query syntax in java using filter and group by if possible

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am new in DDB and I have the data listed below in my DDB table.

| Object | Item | Category | Name | RecommendedDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| book | item1 | Category1 | Name1 | 20220101 |
| book | item2 | Category1 | Name2 | 20220101 |
| book | item1 | Category1 | Name1 | 20220102 |
| book | item2 | Category1 | Name2 | 20220102 |
| book | item3 | Category1 | Name3 | 20220102 |
| book | item3 | Category2 | Name1 | 20220102 |

What is the recommendation to create the GSI based on to fetch the following data:

```
GetItems(Object,Category) -->   GetItems(book,Category1)
```

Should only return rows that have the latest RecommendedDate filtered by Object and Category. What does the query look like?

| Object | Item | Category | Name | RecommendedDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| book | item1 | Category1 | Name1 | 20220102 |
| book | item2 | Category1 | Name2 | 20220102 |

Comment: Hello, what are your pk and sk? You can't do a group by in DDB, maybe have a look at this talk from Alex DeBrie, to get a better understanding of DDB features and trade offs: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yNOVamgIXGQ

Comment: I am not sure based on the current schema what to set as a PK and SK